# Mutate only focus of Store Comonad?

Tags: haskell, comonad, representable

I'm using [Control.Comonad.Representable.Store](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Control-Comonad-Representable-Store.html) to represent a grid object for a game; the grid is: `type Grid = Store (Compose Vector Vector) a`; where Vector has a representable instance indexed by `Int`.

This allows me to use comonadic `extend` and `experiment` for grid squares to interact with their neighbours, and for me to use the focus of the Store monad (indicated by `pos`) as a cursor into the grid.

What I'm looking for is a reasonable way to set the value at the focus of the store, or to use the `Representable` instance of `Compose Vector Vector` to set/mutate values at a given index. So far as I can tell, using the tools in `Comonad` and `Representable` I can only get values out of the structure, I can't find any function like: `over :: ComonadStore s w => (a -> a) -> w a -> w a` or even `Representable f => set :: f a -> Rep f -> a -> f a`.

Sure, I can index into the vectors, adjust the value, then set it back at its index; or even use `tabulate` to rebuild the structure but with the adjustments made, but those sound inefficient and inelegent. It seems like some combination of these typeclasses would be able to do this for me; or if there's some other constraint/typeclass that I'm missing which could help out here.

Thanks!

Comment: Could `fmap` be the function that you're looking for?

Comment: @MarkSeemann `fmap` isn't quite right, because it alters every value in the functor. The questioneer is looking to alter only the one at the comonad's focus, zipper-style.

Comment: I'm fairly sure I've addressed this in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49585295/lenses-over-comonads-or-representable/49586925#49586925) to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49585295/lenses-over-comonads-or-representable), so I'm going to close this one as a dupe. Please let me know if you think I'm wrong about that though.