# Lenses over Comonads or Representable

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, comonad, representable

Here's a more specific variant of this question: [Mutate only focus of Store Comonad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49585262/mutate-only-focus-of-store-comonad), for the benefit of not asking more than one question at once.

Are there any lenses compatible with [Control.Lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) which allow me to interact with the focus of a comonad (the value from `extract`) or with the index/value of the Store Comonad (`pos`)?

It seems like lenses may be of some use here, but I have been unable to find anything which fits; any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think there are two separate questions here: "can I use lenses to work with a `Comonad`'s focus?" and "can I use indexed optics to work with `Representable` functors?" I've answered the first one below, but you should extract the second one into another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Comonad` doesn't give you any way to write back to the comonad's focus, so you can't write a general `Lens` for `extract`. But [it is very easy to turn any old function into a `Getter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Lens-Getter.html#v:to):

```
extracted :: Comonad w => Getter (w a) a
extracted = to extract
```

Of course many comonads *do* allow you to write into the focus - `Store`, as you mentioned, but also (including but not limited to) `Env`, `Traced` and `Identity`.

```
-- I suspect some of these laws are redundant:
--   write id = id
--   write f . write g = write (f . g)
--   extract . write f = f . extract
--   duplicate . write f = write (write f) . duplicate
--   write (const (extract w)) w = w
class Comonad w => ComonadWritable w where
    write :: (a -> a) -> w a -> w a

instance ComonadWritable Identity where
    write f (Identity x) = Identity (f x)

-- law-abiding "up to Eq"
instance (Eq s, ComonadWritable w) => ComonadWritable (StoreT s w) where
    write f (StoreT w s) = StoreT (write g w) s
        where
            g k s'
                | s' == s = f (k s')
                | otherwise = k s'

-- law-abiding "up to Eq"
instance (Eq m, Monoid m, ComonadWritable w) => ComonadWritable (TracedT m w) where
    write f (TracedT w) = TracedT (write g w)
        where
            g k m
                | m == mempty = f (k m)
                | otherwise = k m

instance ComonadWritable w => ComonadWritable (EnvT e w) where
    write f (EnvT e w) = EnvT e (write f w)
```

Given `ComonadWritable` it's easy to construct a `Lens` for a comonad's focus.

```
focus :: ComonadWritable w => Lens' (w a) a
focus = lens extract (\w x -> write (const x) w)
```

One note on efficiency: `StoreT` and `TracedT`'s `write` implementations build a chain of functions with equality checks on the way down, so `extract` is O(n) in the number of `write` calls. Since you mentioned you're using a `Representable` comonad `w`, you could implement some clever strategy of batching up edits and reifying them into an actual `w` every so often. Or you could store edits in a `Map` (strengthening the `Eq` constraint to `Ord`) and delegate to the underlying `w` when it turns out an element hasn't been edited. I'll leave that part to you.

Comment: This is helpful, but the O(n) is a concern I'm concerned about; I can do much better using the underlying Vectors (from the other question) and composing `ix` lenses; thanks though this is interesting!

Comment: "I can do much better using the underlying Vectors" - well, when you edit an element of an immutable vector you have to copy the whole thing, so you get O(1) `extract` at the expense of a `write` which is O(n) in the size of the vector. That's why I suggested batching up edits and only building a new `w` every so often, that way you amortise out the costs and get O(1) for both read and write.

Comment: @dfeuer The `write (const (extract w)) w = w` law says that `write` targets no more than one `a` in a `w a` (namely the one that `extract` targets). I came up with this based on the get-then-set `Lens` law.

Comment: Good question, though. You should undelete your comment!